Avoid evaluation of variables in a Makefile
I'm trying to create a Makefile, recovering the credentials from AWS Secrets manager, and pass it to Skaffold, but when I recover the password and I try sending it to the function it fails, because it is being evaluated.
And it happens again when I try to pass it as variables to skaffold with PG_USER=$(PG_USER) \ PG_PASSWORD=$(PG_PASSWORD) \.
I tried fixing it with quotes, and double quotes, and adding $$ as other answers were saying, but at the end nothing worked. Not sure how to fix it, or where I could improve my skills in this area, I feel I only learn on these situations of doing, but then I'm in a hurry and don't enjoy it.
Makefile
production-release:
    $(eval creds := $(shell aws --profile $(AWS_PROFILE) secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id $(RDS_SECRET_ID) --query SecretString --output json))
    $(eval user := $(shell echo $(creds) | jq -r .username))
    $(eval password := $(shell echo $(creds) | jq -r .password))
    @$(MAKE) .skaffold-build PROFILE=production PG_USER=$(user) PG_PASSWORD=$(password)

Output:
/bin/bash: line 1: GPhADd-6Y: No such file or directory

The whole password is O}Kyfg|42t$~*!.w_f<GPhADd-6Y

You should never use $(eval in a makefile recipe -- it only makes sense at the makefile definition level.  It is not even clear what it means to call eval in a recipe.

I agree with your advice to not use $(eval ...) in a makefile recipe, but it IS clear what it means.  The argument to the $(eval ...) will be processed as if it was a makefile regardless where it appears, including in a recipe.

As I said below, your problem is you are not quoting the argument in your recipe.  And, you should be using single-quotes not double-quotes.  However, be aware that this will fail if your password contains single-quote characters.  To be 100% sure that it will not fail regardless of the content of the password you can use PG_PASSWORD='$(subst ','\'',$(password))' etc.

And, please head John Bollinger's most excellent advice below: it's always, always wrong to add @ to your recipes until AFTER your makefile works 100% correctly.  Doing otherwise is like sending stdout to /dev/null while trying to figure out why your process doesn't work.


I'm trying to create a Makefile, recovering the credentials from AWS Secrets manager, and pass it to Skaffold, but when I recover the password and I try sending it to the function it fails, because it is being evaluated.

I presume you mean evaluated by the shell.  Yes, it is.  This is one reason why it can be problematic to forward make variables to the shell if you do not have tight control over their values.   It can be hard to ensure that they are quoted appropriately.
The Makefile you show wants to be a shell script instead.  Maybe this one:
#!/bin/sh

creds=$(aws --profile "$AWS_PROFILE" secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id "$RDS_SECRET_ID" --query SecretString --output json)
user=$(echo "$creds" | jq -r .username)
password=$(echo "$creds" | jq -r .password)
make .skaffold-build PROFILE=production PG_USER="$user" PG_PASSWORD="$password"

... or this one:
#!/bin/sh

creds=$(aws --profile "$AWS_PROFILE" secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id "$RDS_SECRET_ID" --query SecretString --output json)
make .skaffold-build \
  PROFILE=production \
  PG_USER="$(echo "$creds" | jq -r .username)" \
  PG_PASSWORD="$(echo "$creds" | jq -r .password)"

Note that I've converted not only creds, user, and password into shell variables, which is probably needed, but also AWS_PROFILE and RDS_SECRET_ID, which is more a function of the conversion to (only) shell script.

If you want to have that inside a makefile, perhaps because there are also other targets in that file that are better suited for make, then don't overthink it.  Either of those variations can be adapted to serve as the recipe for a make target.  For example:
production-release:
        creds=$$(aws --profile "$(AWS_PROFILE)" secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id "$(RDS_SECRET_ID)" --query SecretString --output json); \
        $(MAKE) .skaffold-build \
            PROFILE=production \
            PG_USER="$$(echo "$$creds" | jq -r .username)" \
            PG_PASSWORD="$$(echo "$$creds" | jq -r .password)"

.PHONY: production-release

Note that I have switched AWS_PROFILE and RDS_SECRET_ID back to make variables.  Other than that, I escaped all $ that are to be passed through to the shell by doubling them, and I put the assignment of shell variable creds on the same logical line as the sub-make command, but as a separate shell command.

Additional notes:

do not use $(eval).  Especially not in recipes, but not outside them either.  You can consider revisiting this advice when you've acquired enough expertise to feel safe ignoring me.

avoid $(shell) when you can, which should be most of the time.  It's usually preferable to just write a recipe. In fact, those who use makes other than GNU make don't have $(shell) anyway, and they get along pretty well.

don't suppress echo of recipe lines until you're sure they're working correctly, and consider not doing so even then.



The makefile's variables should not be defined inside a recipe.
If you do not want to obtain password always, and do it only if target is production-release, then you can do it inside conditional based on a goal.
It is also a good idea to quote strings:
ifeq "$(MAKECMDGOALS)" "production-release"
   creds := $(shell aws --profile $(AWS_PROFILE) secretsmanager get-secret-value --secret-id $(RDS_SECRET_ID) --query SecretString --output json)
   user := $(shell echo $(creds) | jq -r .username)
   password := $(shell echo $(creds) | jq -r .password)
endif

production-release:
    @$(MAKE) .skaffold-build PROFILE=production PG_USER="$(user)" PG_PASSWORD="$(password)"


I was doing some tests, and looks like the problemis because in the password there is $~, so even after using the quotes, looks like they have been removed in the first evaluation...
But yeah, you are totally right about using them inside the quotes, and seems that in the last 5h didn't try to quote both variables...fml

Tried exactly your code, but inside the .skaffold-build if you do a $(password), it removes the $- from the string :(

Note that this will break if production-release is one of multiple goal targets.

@set92 You can try adding sed "s/[$]/\$\$/g" to how you initially read password (like pwd=$(shell echo | jq | sed)) This will ensure that each dollar in the password variable would be doubled and that can preserve it for use in the recipe, there it would become a single symbol.  Or just forbid using "bad" symbols in the password :)

You should use single quotes in your recipe, not double quotes.  If you use double-quotes then the shell will expand any $ as a shell variable.  So you want ... PG_USER='$(user)' ... etc.
